# Python recursion error with no recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to python, and I'm building a web crawler for funsies/educational purposes. I don't use any recursive functions, but I still get the 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded' error. I'm really confused, and kinda feel like I'm missing something obvious or just misunderstanding something. Am I somehow recursing, or could it be related to my large loops? The idea is to crawl the web until you've crawled 10k pages.

UPDATES:

Latest Code is here: http://pastebin.com/4v5GT7ft

Stack Trace is Here: http://pastebin.com/9GzAxZM9

Looks like my issue is trying to call str() on a URL that is not encoded properly. I've tried decoding the URLs and then ecoding them to unicode, but I was never able to do it successfully. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please do include the *full* traceback of python exceptions. That saves us all having to *guess* where the error occurred.

Comment: If you're parsing HTML you *are* using recursive functions...I suggest that when you fail you dump the page variable to see if the Html is misformed

Comment: I'm at work now, I'll post the full traceback when I get home tonight. Sorry.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl: Not necessarily. You can write a purely iterative parser, and instead of recursively crawling any links found just push them onto the end of the queue.

Comment: Actually there is a way of avoiding the recursion limits using enhanced generators and trampolines(later I'll search for a link to an html parser that used this strategy to avoid this error).

Comment: Try to change your log() function to do nothing (i.e. def log(): pass and comment out the rest of the function). I suspect you have an error in log() which has log() called again and so on.

Comment: Did you really shorten this as much as you could? For example, is opening an mdb database essential to the problem? (That's something most of us can't test—even if we _had_ your database, which we don't.)

Comment: Meanwhile, even if I strip out all the database-related stuff, there's at least one `IndentationError` that I have to guess at (in `crawl_web`, `if page not in crawled:` doesn't have anything indented under it, and the comments around it aren't at the same indentation levels as the corresponding code, etc.).

Comment: And finally, you're clearly `from foo import Bar`ing a whole lot of stuff that you don't show. I think I've fixed it all up at http://pastebin.com/rCJriEu5 (you will need to install `lxml`, because the built in parser, at least with Python 2.7.2, can't handle some of the sites you point at).

Comment: As a side note: Why are you doing base URL handling manually? You're not actually doing it correctly (you only handle absolute paths, you ignore the `base` tag, you treat email or anything else that's not http(s) as a relative URL, etc.). Also, you're doing stuff like `link['href'][0:7] == "http://"` instead of using a real URL splitting function, or at least `startswith`. I don't think this is causing your immediate problem, but it does raise a red flag that you may be reimplementing wheels that you don't actually know how to implement…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you gave us doesn't actually run (it's missing all the `import` statements, and it has indentation errors, and so on), and it requires a JET database we don't have and a third-party module to read it, and it's hardcoded to use pre-existing directories in your home directory.

I've attempted to fix all of that at http://pastebin.com/rCJriEu5 (which requires `lxml` and `bs4`—if you were using a different parsing library or BS3, I can try it that way).

And when I run it, it seems to work. It's 31.73% complete, with no errors yet. Even if I do a `sys.setrecusionlimit(50)` at the start of the file, it still seems to work (3.67% complete so far).

So, whatever is wrong in your code is apparently in code you haven't showed us.

Comment: It seems to fail for me around 1500 pages scanned. I know that doesn't make sense, it's just my observation. Sorry about removing import statments, I thought that would be helpful (I was wrong). I've uploaded the full code here: http://pastebin.com/q9KCrQrL (Should get rid of the indentation errors)

As for the database, it's just a local mysql db, named python, with a user named and password equaling python. All the log files should auto-create (the directory should too, thanks to your code). I was getting the traceback wrong, so I'm still working on getting that.

Comment: @Brian: Without the traceback, it's hard to be sure what's going on… but my guess is that the recursion limit is actually happening _inside the HTML parser_. See [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for details on the different parsers `bs4` can use, but if you're falling back to the default, especially on 2.7.2/3.1.0 or earlier, it sucks in many ways. When I test with 2.7.2, it fails on 4 of the first 100 files (at least two different errors, neither of which is a recursion error).

Comment: @Brian: And a really quick way to test that: Whichever link it failed on, put that link at the start of the started `deque`, and see if it now fails on the first page instead of the 1500th.

Comment: Huzzah! I finally have a full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/9GzAxZM9 This is my updated code: http://pastebin.com/4v5GT7ft

Looks like the problem comes from the log function (like @uselpa stated), specifically trying to convert the url to a string so I could log it properly.

This is a symptom of a larger problem I've been having, which is the URL encodings. I tried decoding them and then encoding them to unicode, but I never had any luck. (That's why I check for unicode errors everywhere) Any adivce on how to properly decode/encode would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Brian: OK, so _which link is this happening on_? If it's happening in the same place consistently, but it takes waiting through 1500-odd fetches to repro it, you're making it much harder for people to debug this for you.

Comment: @Brian: Also, what do you mean by "encoding them to unicode"? The whole point of encoding is that you take a Unicode string and encode it to some 8-bit charset (UTF-8, Latin-1, Shift-JIS, whatever). If you're trying to encode from something else to unicode… well, that could explain why it's not working. At any rate, with HTML, you need to know the charset to decode from, which may be in the HTTP headers, the HTML `head` section, or implicit (defaulted). So, if you don't let `bs4` try to do it for you automagically, you need to write the code to handle that properly.